# How does cmd work way faster(like 10x) than python idle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-idle

I've written this usual fibonacci python code in python official idle;

```
def fib(n):
     a, b = 0, 1
     while a < n:
         print(a, end=' ')
         a, b = b, a+b
     print()
fib(10000000)
```

When i increased n,like i did in exemple, in idle it've taken around 30s-60s to finish it, after this,

I saved the python file as fibo.py and I ve opened it on cmd by importing module after opening python in cmd with -py extension.

Even if you put a very big number n in cmd, the process ends in less than 2 seconds always. Its a very very very high speed, but this isn't same for python idle,

Any answer would be appriciated.

Comment: IDLE probably handles I/O differently, making the `print`s slower. Try comparing the two with only a single print at the end of the function

Comment: Try without the `print()` call inside the  while loop. Input/output is often a bottle neck.

Comment: Cmd also printing the numbers, but I agree with the idea that print slows the process of Python. Without prints they both are working pretty fast! Thanks for the comments.

Comment: See the linked duplicate I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually its not dublicate because i’m askin why cmd is too fast here..

Comment: @AliÖztürk What do you mean by "too fast"? Too fast for what? Is it giving the wrong answer?

Comment: its giving the right answer but while its taking 30s in idle its taking 2s in cmd, i mean the huge difference with “too fast”

Comment: @glibdud too fast simply means it executes the same code, giving exactly the same results but using fewer seconds/microseconds

Comment: @AliÖztürk If it only takes 2 seconds to get the correct answer, then that's how long it should take. Thus, what you're actually asking is why Idle *doesn't* do it in two seconds, and I agree that the duplicate is the most likely reason why.

Comment: @glibdud nope mate, i’m asking why Cmd is working that fast? You accomplish with same speed even if you hugely increase the number . That s what i was asking, it s written already, no?

Comment: @AliÖztürk That has nothing to do with cmd or Idle; Fibonacci just isn't a very complex algorithm. A computer can do a *lot* of simple operations in two seconds. More time is probably being spent compiling the code than actually running it.

Comment: @glibdud ok, so it’s because of the algorithm only you say? So there s no effect of being command prompt?

Comment: @AliÖztürk Correct, the reason Idle isn't going as fast as cmd is because of the string handling.

Comment: @glibdud Ok, thanks

Comment: Idle executes your code in a separate process.  Each print call generates a string that is encoded to bytes, sent through a socket, decoded back to a string, and then inserted into a GUI text widget that can contain a million short lines but slows down with lone lines.  If you removed `end = '  '` I expect IDLE would run faster, whereas a Windows console would keep only the last 300 (default) to 9999 lines.